# TypeError when trying to open file

Tags: python, typeerror

I wrote the following Python code:

```
# code that reads the file line by line
def read_the_file(file_to_read):
    f = open('test.nml','r')
    line = f.readline()
    print("1. Line is : ", line)
    if '<?xml version="1.0"' in line:
        next_line = f.readline()
        print("2. Next line is : ", next_line)
        write_f = open('myfile', 'w')
        while '</doc>' not in next_line:
            write_f.write(next_line)
            next_line = f.readline()
            print("3. Next line is : ", next_line)
        write_f.close()
    return write_f

# code that processes the xml file
def process_the_xml_file(file_to_process):
    print("5. File to process is : ", file_to_process)
    file = open(file_to_process, 'r')
    lines=file.readlines()
    print(lines) 
    file.close()


# calling the code to read the file and process the xml
path_to_file='test.nml'   
write_f=read_the_file(path_to_file)   
print("4. Write f is : ", write_f) 
process_the_xml_file(write_f)
```

which basically attempts to first write and then read a file. The code gives the following error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: can u show full error message..??

Comment: The error should also give the line number it occurs on.

Comment: Try to create a minimal piece of code with the same problem. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Two notes: 1. You are creating `write_f` inside `if` statement and then returning it in  `read_the_file`. Consider what happens if the `if` statement is not executed. 2. Inside the `if` statement you are closing `write_f` file (which is returned right after).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `return write_f` in read_the_file to `return write_f.name`.

write_f is the file handler object, you need to pass the name of the file to process_the_xml_file, not the file handler object.

Comment: I think this gets the job done thanks. Will come back with any more queries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are using a closed file handle and not a string in the process_the_xml_file method.

read_the_file returns a file handle and not the name of the file.

Comment: You could `return write_f.name` in the `read_the_file` function.